# Cache directory and file list to prevent hard drive access when browsing contents

Tags: directory, cache

I have 7 hard drives that are in a virtual pool (mhddfs) so they appear as one directory. I put them to sleep after 5 minutes of inactivity to save a significant chunk of power.

The problem with this is that it takes quite a while to spin 7 drives one by one down, not to mention the wear and power usage that occurs. I would like to cache the file and directory list so that only when a file is actually requested for access, does the drive spin up.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a possibility to lock the file system meta data in the cache but (if there are not too many files) you can read the meta data regularly in order to keep it in the cache:

```
find /path/to/dir -printf ""
```

Comment: I think that would somewhat defeat the purpose as it would wake the drives or prevent them sleeping. Also there are a lot of files as you would expect from 31TB :)

Comment: @DominicM That would wake the drives only if the meta data does not fit into the cache. Otherwise the data would be read from the cache and be marked as recently-read so that it is not thrown out of the cache.

Comment: Maybe I should try it out, how would I run this exactly? Also would it cache to ram or swap? I have only 4gb ram now and 60gb ssd now, much space would it require approx? There must be at least 70k files.

Comment: @DominicM To tell the truth: I have no idea how much space it requires. `top` and `free` show you the amount of RAM used for the cache. You could reboot the system (at best with minimal activity i.e. runlevel 1 or 2), note the amount of cache RAM, run the `find` command line and check the values of cache RAM and unused RAM afterwards. If the unused RAM has dropped to zero then the caching would require more than available. If it turns out to be acceptable with respect to the RAM requirement then you may run `find` from `cron` every few minutes.

Comment: How does running a cron that attempts to find files not wake the disks?

Comment: @DominicM Because it is the task of a cache to replace the disk access.

Comment: ah, tipped you over 20000. Do i get a medal for that :-)

Comment: @1_CR Not so easy to notice (due to rounding)... I guess the chances for such a badge proposal would be rather low. Too many second thoughts in voting...

Comment: @HaukeLaging That makes sense but if the cron job only uses cache how is it ever going to refresh itself when files change?

Comment: @DominicM File changes are written to the page cage first, then to the disk.

Comment: @haukelaging, I meant that half in jest. Anyways, godspeed for the next 10000

Comment: @HaukeLaging I tried adding the command you suggested as a cron job but none of the 7 drives spin down when before at least a few were spun down. Maybe it's the lack of ram but 4GB should be enough for the contents of at least 1 drive...